# Execute query & display results using AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need some help getting AJAX to work within a CodeIgniter project. Based off of a user's selection, I want to use AJAX to send a variable (Agency_Number) to my controller to execute and get query results back within my view.

Example:

1. User selects the Agency Number from the dropdown list
2. Agency Number sent to the controller using AJAX
3. Agency Number sent to model to execute query to select that agency's info from database.
4. Form inputs, such as Program_Host_Name, get populated with Agency information.

I'm able to successfully execute the query and get the Program Host Name to populate within my form, however, my select input disappears from the page when the information is returned. I suppose this is caused by reloading my view, which I don't think I should be doing in the first place. I'm not sure how to pass the Program_Host_Name value back to my view without doing this though.

Thanks for any help y'all can give!

Here's my view (create_opportunity.php)

```
<form submit="opportunity/create_opportunity" id="validation-form" method="POST">
<select id="Agency_Number">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach ($agencies as $agency):?>
  <option value="<?php echo $agency->Agency_Number;?>"><?php echo $agency->Agency_Number;?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Program_Host_Name" value="<?php echo $Program_Host_Name ?>"/>
</form>
```

Here's my script within the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Lookup').click(function() {

    var AgencyNumber = $('#Agency_Number').val();

    if (!AgencyNumber || AgencyNumber == 'Agency_Number') {
        alert('Please enter an Agency Number');
        return false;
    }

    var form_data = {
        Agency_Number: $('#Agency_Number').val(),
        ajax: '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('opportunity/create_opportunity'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('body').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Here's my controller (opportunity.php)

```
function create_opportunity() {

  $this->data['agencies'] = $this->ion_auth_model->get_agencies();

  if($this->input->post('ajax')) {
    $Agency_Number = $this->input->post('Agency_Number');
    $agency = $this->ion_auth_model->get_agency($Agency_Number)->row();
    $this->data['Program_Host_Name'] = $agency->Name;
    $this->data['Address_1'] = $agency->Address_1;
  } 

    $this->data['main_content'] = 'create_opportunity';
    $this->load->view('./_blocks/template', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: If you execute create_opportunity.php on its own, does it print out properly? Have you watched the request / response in your browser's console?

Comment: Yup, it prints out properly on its own. Nothing out of the ordinary with the console results either.

Comment: The entire body of the create_opportunity.php gets returned via AJAX? Add an `:error` handler to your AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing returning the entire body isn't ideal but that's how I was able to get it semi-working. I added error: function(thrownError) { alert(thrownError); } to the request and received no response.

Comment: No, it's absolutely ideal, because it is what you're requesting. try this in the success function - `$('body').append(msg);` I think I understand your issue now.

Comment: Doing this repeats my page content. So, if I scroll down on my page after clicking 'Lookup' I see the same content. The Agency Number field does stay intact on my original view, but it disappears on the repeated view, which is where the results also display.

Comment: Also, I can echo a variable in my controller and get that value back using $('#Program_Host_Name').val(msg);. However, I need to get the value back for multiple variables and don't see how this is possible using my current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use json_encode() to convert an associative array from PHP into JSON and then used $.getJSON() to return the JavaScript array.

Here's my working script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Lookup').click(function() {

    var AgencyNumber = $('#Agency_Number').val();

    if (!AgencyNumber || AgencyNumber == 'Agency_Number') {
        alert('Please enter an Agency Number');
        return false;
    }

    var form_data = {
        Agency_Number: $('#Agency_Number').val(),
        ajax: '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('opportunity/get_agency'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Program_Host_Name').val(data.Program_Host_Name);
            $('#Address_Line_1').val(data.Address_1);
        },
        error: function(thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Here's my working controller:

```
function get_agency() {

    if($this->input->post('ajax')) {
        $Agency_Number = $this->input->post('Agency_Number');

        $agency = $this->ion_auth_model->get_agency($Agency_Number)->row();

        echo json_encode(
            array(  "Program_Host_Name" => "$agency->Name",
                    "Address_1" => "$agency->Address_1"
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!